# Minimal group of Pokémon for the complete exploration moves set

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I own Pokémon Omega Ruby, not Pokémon Alpha Sapphire and I'm only starting it.

I'd like a team for exploration, catching and finishing the story.

I have my catcher, I'm building my hitters but I miss my explorers yet.

So my question is what is the smallest group possible of Pokémon I could use so that I can teach them all the story-needed moves? By that, I mean moves like Cut, Rock Smash, Surf, Fly, etc. Actually all moves that have a real impact to access all parts of the story and that must be used again and again.

*Edit:*

For clarity, I expect that the list doesn't contain any pokémon described as "unobtainable" in ORAS. See http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/unobtainable.shtml for the complete list of Pokémon that are not allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to gaymer_dude on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/2n63zd/whats_the_best_hm_slave_for_oras/):

> Since, according to this thread, **Sharpedo** is the best Pokemon to Surf on, I did some research. Sharpedo can learn Surf, Cut, Dive, and Waterfall. **Skarmory**, a good Pokemon in its own right, learns the other moves you need (Fly, Cut, and Rock Smash). So that's pretty neat!

**So the smallest group of explorers is 2**

Comment: Okay, thanks. This is it. I'd like to mention that Strength is apparently needed. So Sharpedo can use Strength instead of Cut, and Skarmory the 3 missing HMs.

Comment: @ogregoire I'd like to add here that Fly is not needed to progress and eventually becomes obsolete through the Eon Flute (given after defeating Groudon/Kyogre). Also worth mentioning would be Flash, though it's not absolutely necessary for exploration either.

Comment: Indeed, Flash can be added to Skarmory as its 4th move. So the answer stays the same. Any "extra" move would require an extra pokémon. ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are *many* combinations of just two Pokémon that can cover every HM.

The Pokemon Database has [this awesome chart](http://pokemondb.net/omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire/hms) that can be used to find "HM slaves". I find it most useful to filter "Hoenn only", and then sort by the rightmost column (total number learnable). It should look something like this snippet:

[image: oras hm chart]

The first thing I notice is that Cut and Fly aren't very common together, so if we cover both of those with one guy (plus at least one more to make 3+), that will leave us more options for the other.

For that, your options are Latias, Latios, Tropius, and Salamence. You can then pick *anything* in the top 15 or so on the chart (and others below, depending on which 3rd/4th moves you give them), giving plenty of combos already. Personally, I'm a fan of Tropius for this role, if only to give his existence meaning. He's just so *sad* otherwise. He can learn Cut/Fly/Strength/RockSmash, so the only things needed are Surf/Waterfall/Dive, which are commonly all available on one Pokémon (most decent water types).

Of course, you could use separate Cut/Fly pokes, and that opens up a few more possibilities. For example, you can cover all your bases with Crawdaunt(everything but Fly) and any flier with at least 3 HMs available.

In the end, there are a lot of ways you can do it. Pick your favorites and go with that.

Comment: I know I didn't mention Flash, but you can TM it to so many that it's basically an afterthought IMO. It's also almost useless, since in this generation you can just tilt the screen to see a brighter image in "dark" caves (rather than the pure black of some earlier games).

Comment: Never knew about this website.  Awesome tip

Answer (score -1):

There's a way to get all (in my opinion) relevant field moves in 2 Pokemon thanks to a little trick. And you can use Sharpedo for its double speed Surf, too.

It is a little tough to set up, but if you think it's worth it, this can make quite the difference. I also found a path to set all that up while playing through.

So for the final team, you use **Carvanha**/**Sharpedo** and teach it **Surf**, **Strength**, **Waterfall** and **Dive** and breed up a **Paras(ect)** with **Sweet Scent** and teach it **Cut** and **Rock Smash**. For the last slot, you alternate between **Flash** and **Dig**, both of which are available and easily obtained early on as TMs (which are infinite use now, yay!).
For your Flying needs, you have the Eon Flute!

So, with only 2 Pokemon, you covered a total of 10 moves thanks to some little trickery: Cut, Fly, Surf, Strength, Waterfall, Rock Smash, Dive, Flash, Dig and Sweet Scent.

As for the path to get there:

- The first field move you gain access to is Cut. Catch a Zigzagoon early on, it can learn Cut and will later be able to learn Rock Smash and Surf, as well as Strength once it evolves.
- As soon as you can, also get a Nincada. It can be taught Flash and Dig until you get Paras.
- Carvanha is available shortly after using Surf the first time (you get the Good Rod once you arrive at the other shore the first time you have to Surf to get going, and can use it then and there to get a Carvanha). Once you have it, teach it Surf and level it up to 30 so it evolves. Then teach it Rock Smash and Strength, teach Nincada Cut and replace Linoone.
- Tropius learns Cut, Fly and Sweet Scent and can be used to breed Sweet Scent into Paras later. It's available shortly before being able to use Fly (on route 119). Get one when you're there, teach it all 3 of those moves (you need to use a Heart Scale or breed it to get to Sweet Scent) and Flash, then replace Nincada. This is the time you'll use your Escape Ropes instead of Dig unless one of your other team Pokemon has Dig.
- Once you get it, teach Sharpedo Dive as its fourth move.
- The next step is after getting the Eon flute. You don't need Fly any more, so you can go get a Paras, breed Sweet Scent into it, teach it Cut, Rock Smash and Flash or Dig (remember, you'll switch those around with the TMs as you need each one), then replace the Tropius with it.
- Lastly, go visit the Move Deleter to get Rock Smash off Sharpedo so you have the last slot free for Waterfall once you get access to it.